# AWS Systems Manager Session Manager: Failed to login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I am running a WordPress site on EC2 of Amazon Linux AMI. Instance is running behind auto-scaling and load balancer.

The problem is, after a new instance is launched, I can log in to that instance by Session Manager without any problem. But after several hours passed (For example 2 or 3 hours), I cannot login to that instance any more. It displays:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICLaA.png)

I did not understand why this is happening. Can anyone suggest any ideas?

Comment: Probably your instance is running out of ram/disk and is not responsive.

Comment: If you Reboot the instance via the EC2 management console, are you then able to connect? In the Monitoring tab of the instance in the EC2 management console, what does the **CPU Utilization** chart show?

Comment: @Marcin  I found memory was being used nearly 85%. So changed the ec2 instance type from t3micro to t3 medium. Now under observation

Answer (score -2):

Basically this is happening because your Instance is not Systems Manager Managed. To confirm, go to Systems Manager console, click on Fleet manager and see if your instance is listed out with an Online Ping status.
If not, then you should make it managed first. This is the prerequisite step. Related [article](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/systems-manager-ec2-instance-not-appear) for this to follow.

If you want some sort of automated way, you can leverage AWSSupport-TroubleshootSessionManager, an AWS Systems Manager automation runbook to do it. Check [this](https://www.repost.aws/articles/AR8nK-hk2aQoef9tTTE8CurQ/support-automation-workflow-saw-runbook-troubleshoot-aws-systems-manager-session-manager) repost article about this runbook.